# Inserted View in Simplenews excluded from Email but included on website

Tags: emails

Drupal 7.14, Simplenews 7.x-1.0-rc1, Insert View 7.x-2.0, Views 7.x-3.3

I have created a view ("birthdays"), a newsletter and inserted the view [view:birthdays]. The view is inserted and displayed correctly when I display the newsletter on the website. The problem is - the view is not included when I email the newsletter. I am using MailSystem, MimeMail, all set to send HTML, which otherwise works correctly. Ideas?